# Wrong user input C#/Python

Tags: c#, python, input

I wrote a console application in Python for a teacher a while ago, the usual grading calculations.This bit of code was preventing invalid input:

```
    while True:
    try:    
        Paper2 = float(input("Enter grade: "))  
    except ValueError:  
        print ("༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ error!")
        continue    
    if Paper2 > 10:
        print ("༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ error!")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

How does one `Try/except ValueError` in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float Paper2;
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        Paper2 = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (Paper2 > 10)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ error!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) `Try/except ValueError` is for exception handling. You perform the same in `C#` using `try .. catch` block like

```
try
{
  // your code logic which may raise exception
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
 //handle the exception do necessary stuff like logging
}
finally
{
 //perform cleanup here
}
```

See more on [Exceptions and Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx)